# Node.JS - Check result exists before running function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I'm relatively new to Node JS. I'm attempting to query the database, and then simply emit that data to the front end using socket.io, however I've noticed that it is intermittently sending the data / not sending the data to the front end. I'm assuming that the reason behind this is because the query has not yet finished yet, and was wondering how you'd wait for the result to be accessible before continuing?

I'm using npm mysql to access the database within the socket such as below:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'db'
    }
);
```

Here is my query:

```
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, result, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('emitFunction', result);
    });
```

Comment: I personally just take care of this sort of thing on my front end and not on node.

Comment: *"I'm assuming that the reason behind this is because the query has not yet finished yet."*  No, that isn't it. The `function` (callback) doesn't fire *until* the results are there.  That's the entire reason why `socket.emit(...)` is inside the callback function, rather than simply being the next statement after the query.  Log the result before writing to the socket.  Log some timestamps, too.  Log, log, log.

Answer (score 1):

The callback only called after query done so the result should available inside the callback function. Log both err and result to see what happened

Comment: I see. I've just created a callback and it's looking promising so far. Will let you know how I get on as it's getting late here. Thanks for the advice.